# How i can upgrade my navbar from one line to two line?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

So recently I am working on a website whose navbar look like this [image]

But as I want to change my navbar to this [image]

I have tried by myself using padding and margins but somehow its not working and not at all responsive so how i can make navbar like in image 2 ?? Pls help

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an effort and show your code.

Answer (score -1):

You could use **flexbox**.

In your Header's CSS put `display: flex;` to transform it in a flex container and then `flex-direction: column;` to make it exhibit the elements one above the other.

Now, create two divs inside the header — one containing the elements in the upper part and the other containing the bottom ones — then place in the first div the elements you want above and in the second div the ones you want below.

Example HTML:

```
<header>
  <div>
    <input class="search">
    <img class="logo">
    <button>Sign-in</button>
    <button>Cart</button>
    <button>Wishlist</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/products">Shop</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The question is both of poor quality and specifically related to Bootstrap. It shouldn't have been answered, but if you are going to answer your solution should reflect that.